# What location do I copy my standalone "exe" application's App.Config file

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

I've created windows form application (say MyApplication) in visual studio 2015. I've added App.Config to my project so that my code can pick up configuration values like connection string. Everything is working fine when I run my application from visual studio. When I build the EXE file, I can figure out that in my Debug/Release folder I've my app.config file with name "MyApplication.exe.config". But, when I try to run MyApplication.exe as a standalone application, my application crashes as it could not find the app.config file.

Can anybody please let me know, at what should I put/copy "MyApplication.exe.config" (e.g. System32 etc.) so that my application can use this config file?

Any idea on this would be of great help.

Comment: .Net apps don't crash because they can't find their .config file. They crash because developers assume values they read from the config are not null or have sensible values.

Comment: @rene If this is the case then why the application doesn't crash when I run it through visual studio

Comment: .... because VS copies the app.config (and names it [exe filename].config) to the output folder... as you already concluded yourself ....

Answer (score 1):

In the same directory location where your exe file is located because your executable file expects its configuration file to be placed in the same location.